# Echoing variables that have ' in them

Tags: php, variables, echo

I have this echo,

```
echo "<a href = 'showdetails.php?name='$name'&type=movie'> </a>";
```

that is working as intend, but if

```
$name = Gulliver's Travels;
```

for example, I will only receive Gulliver in the other page.

Is there any way of circumventing this?

Thanks,

Zenshi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go for [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) because you are using it as part of an URL:

```
echo "<a href = 'showdetails.php?name=".urlencode($name)."&type=movie'> </a>";
```

Comment: That doesn't work, I only get showdetails.php?name= , not even the type is passed...

Comment: I removed the apostrophs from around the `name` value - try the code now

Answer (score 5):

There are many characters that don't belong in URLs, so encode them all properly:

```
echo '<a href="showdetails.php?name=' . urlencode($name) . '&type=movie"> </a>';
```

The `href` value should be enclosed in double quotes, not single quotes, since single quotes are allowed in URLs but double quotes aren't.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

If you were putting this in any other type of HTML output than a link, you'd want to use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

Comment: Hmmm, if i put that in mine echo '<a href="showdetails.php?name=' . urlencode($name) . '&type=movie"> <img class= "resize" src = '$path' /> </a>'; it gives me an error... (Can be a dumb mistake from my part, been at this for 6 hours straight)

Comment: The string is single quoted, you can't use single quotes around $path and need to concatenate $path's value rather than embed it in the string.

Comment: What do you mean by "concatenate $path's value rather than embed it in the string"? 
Also, how come if i use it like this: echo "<a href = 'showdetails.php?name=$name&type=movie'> <img class='resize' src = '$path' /> </a>"; it works? (The $path part, I mean...)

Comment: Maybe you should read the [syntax section of the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)? Variables are interpolated when within a double quoted string but not a single quoted string. That "works" but now you're back to your HTML breaking when $name contains double quotes.